# Modifying an image/3d Array in R

Tags: arrays, r, tiff

I'm very familiar with C but am new to R and trying to make sure I'm handling data types properly.  Is there a `*apply` type function I could be using instead of two loops to iterate over the first two dimensions of a 3d array?

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
#Make sure the "tiff" library is installed:
#  apt-get install libtiff5-dev
#  Rscript - <<< "install.packages('tiff',,'http://www.rforge.net/')"

library( "tiff" )
RGBlack <- readTIFF( "Imaging.tif", all=TRUE )
RGBlack <- RGBlack[[2]]

AdjustPixel <- function(pix, background){
    # Blue is always off
    pix[3] = 0

    #Turn red off if > background
    if( pix[1] < background ){ 
            pix[1] <- 0
    }
    else  {
            pix[1] <- 1
    }

    #I green is > background turn on, and turn off red
    if( pix[ 2] > background ) {
            pix[1] <- 0
            pix[2] <- 1
    }
    else {
            pix[2] <- 0
    }
    return(pix)
}


background <- 10/256

#Doesn't Work
#RGBlack <- array( AdjustPixel( RGBlack[, , ], background ), dim=c(512,512,3))

#Works
for( row in 1:dim(RGBlack)[1] ){
    for( col in 1:dim(RGBlack)[2] ) {
            RGBlack[row, col, ] = AdjustPixel( RGBlack[row, col, ], background )
    }
}
```

Array() looks promising but

```
RGBlack <- array( AdjustPixel( RGBlack[,,] ), dim=c(dim1,dim2,3))
```

doesn't seem to make any changes to RGBlack.

Am I missing something or is looping the proper solution?

Comment: Your `AdjustPixel` function doesn't **do** anything, which is why there is no our data.   Depending on the actual operation you intend, there may not be a need for any loops at all, as `R` is vectorized.   Also depending on the intended operation, the output `pix` might be a scalar, a vector, or an array, and you'll have to take that into account.

Comment: I pulled that content out as I didn't feel it added to the question.  When I run the program with the loops the image is changed the way I want it to.

I've added the content of AdjustPixel into the question.

Comment: OK, but sans code how can we tell how `AdjustPixel` reacts when given a scalar, or vector, or matrix is its input (e.g.  `RGBlack[row,col,j]` vs. `RGBlack[row,col,]` vs `RGBlack[row,,]` ) ?  How many elements in `pix`, and in what order are they returned?

Comment: The content of AdjustPixel is in the question now.

Comment: I count three different packages with `readTIFF` functions in them. It's possible they are all the same but it would be more courteous of you to include any `library` calls to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `readTIFF` comes from the `tiff`-package, then it delivers a 3 dimensional array. Using a for-loop to process with `if(){}else{}` statements is going to be very slow.

I think this will be much faster:

Using the first example in `?tiff::readTIFF` for a bit of testing (although I don't have a "background" value.)

```
img[ , , 3] <- 0
img[ , , 1] <-  img[,,1] >= background | img[,,2] >= background
img[ , , 2] <- img[,,2] > background
```

I believe this should be much faster. R uses the "[" and "[<-" operators extensively for access to matrices, arrays, lists and dataframes. You should read the help page for those functions several times, I'd say perhaps even ten times, because there is so much to learn about them.

Comment: Much better, though the logic of the second is line is a bit off.  Should be `img[ , , 1] <-  img[,,1] >= background & img[,,2] < background`
Thank-you.

Comment: Perhaps, ... I'll leave it to you to decide. I used "|" but I may not have considered the Boolean implications when I reversed the direction of the inequalities.